# Add all the lines which does not start with char to the previous line

Tags: python, python-2.7

For a text file :

```
[2018-07-11 20:57:08] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "hello"
[2018-07-11 20:57:19] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): "hi! how is it going?"
[2018-07-11 20:57:19] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "It's going pretty good. 
How about you?
What's good?
Up to anything new?
After a long time"

[2018-07-12 14:05:20] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): I've been doing good too!    
Thank you for asking.
Nothing is new so far. 
Just working on some projects.
[2018-07-12 20:57:19] SYSTEM RESPONSE: Great!
```

I want my output to look something like:

```
    [2018-07-11 20:57:08] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "hello"
    [2018-07-11 20:57:19] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): "hi! how is it going?"


[2018-07-11 20:57:19] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "It's going pretty good. How about you?| What's good? Up to anything new?| After a long time"

    [2018-07-12 14:05:20] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): I've been doing good too!    |Thank you for asking. | Nothing is new so far. | Just working on some projects.
    [2018-07-12 20:57:19] SYSTEM RESPONSE: Great!
```

Basically, all the lines that do not start with a time stamp to go to the previous line. 
So far what I have tried:

```
 a , b = text_from_index.split(",") # so I get the file name and the date from this 
            with open("/home/Desktop/"+ a) as log_fd:
                file = log_fd.readlines()

                x =""

                for line in file:
                    if b in line: # b here is the date. eg- 2018-07-11
                        x = x + "//" + line[11:]
                    else:
                        x=x        
                x= x.replace("//","<br /> \n")
                x= x.replace("]","|")

                x= re.sub(r'\(.+?\)', '', x)
```

so far, I am just able to fetch the lines by search for the date. 
Any suggestion, will help! Thank you!
Please feel free to ask me any questions or further clarification

Comment: This is a trivial task. What did you try?

Comment: Iterate through every line. If it has a date, append it to a new list. If it does not, append it to the last element in the list.

Comment: He's saying post your code. Trim it down to the relevant parts and post the code.

Comment: Thank you for asking me to clarify! I have added my code. Please let me know if you need more code or explanation of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the current line in a var, say `cur_line`. Write the `cur_line` to new file if next line doesn't start with `[`, else append the line to `cur_line`

```
with open('tmp.txt') as in_file, open('out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    lines = in_file.readlines()
    cur_line = ''
    for l in lines:
        l = l.rstrip('\r\n')
        if not l:
            continue
        if l[0] == '[':
            out_file.write(cur_line +'\n')
            cur_line = l
        else:
            cur_line += l
    out_file.write(cur_line +'\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to do this. The below regex is matching your timestamps exactly.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("\[(\d){4}\-(\d){2}\-(\d){2}\s(\d){2}:(\d){2}:(\d){2}\]")

# will match with your timestamp so you can skip these lines and concatenate others
pattern.match(line)
```

A full solution would look something like this:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("\[(\d){4}\-(\d){2}\-(\d){2}\s(\d){2}:(\d){2}:(\d){2}\]")

with open("test.txt") as log_fd:
file = log_fd.readlines()

x =""
last = False

for line in file:
    if not line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
        if pattern.match(line):
            if last:
                x = x + '\n' + line.strip('\r\n')
            else:
                x = x + '\n' + line.strip('\r\n')
        else:
            x = x + ' | ' + line.strip('\r\n')
        last = pattern.match(line)

print(x)
```

It will have a blank line at the beginning of the string, but its solving with your string and just printing out the result. Definitely not the most elegent.